# Why is ASP.NET Core 5 replacing the URL query string with a random query string after the page prerender?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-5.0, page-lifecycle, mudblazor

I am creating an ASP.NET 5 Blazor Server application with MudBlazor.

I have a URL `https://localhost:44324/OperationsAll?Proj_ID=23407&Tail_Nr=TG6R&Location=N`.
The query string is used to initialize the data on the `OperationsAll` page.

It works great in the prerender stage of the lifecyle, retrieving the query string and initializing the page with the correct data in the `Oninitialized()` method.

In the render stage of the lifecycle when `Oninitialized()` is run again, the query string has changed to 'https://localhost:44324/OperationsAll?id=1234ASSAf31', with the id always being something different. This, of course, then causes the page to not have the required data for the final render of the page.

An interesting bit of information is that the query string is not being replaced in the web browser address bar, that still remains as `https://localhost:44324/OperationsAll?Proj_ID=23407&Tail_Nr=TG6R&Location=N`. The query string is being replaced with the random `?id=ASDF!1234` within the `HttpContext`.

Why is the query string being replaced?

How do I keep the query string from changing during the page lifecycle?

Comment: Do you mean that when `Oninitialized()` is called for the second time, does your retrieval string change automatically? I don't have your situation, can you provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Here are the links that might help you: [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0), [Working with Query Strings in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/).

Comment: Yes, the query string is automatically changed within the HttpContext. The web browser address bar is unchanged. I have updated my question with this information. I have previously found and read the links you provided, and they do not provide a solution.

Comment: Did you do anything special to it? Is it possible to monitor `HttpContext`?

Comment: @chen I appreciate your help; I do not know the answers to these questions. From what I have been able to find so far, this might have to do with the way ASP.NET core manages an anonymous user session.  I have created a work-around by using a cookie where I store and retrieve the needed query string values. The cookie lives only long enough for the page to complete rendering.